# using CCOrbitCamera to flip sprite over its Y axis in Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

in Cocos2d i can use CCOrbitCamera action to rotate flip an sprite. Something like this works fine over its x axis:

```
CCOrbitCamera * orbit = [CCOrbitCamera actionWithDuration:2 radius:1 
    deltaRadius:0 angleZ:0 deltaAngleZ:360 angleX:0 deltaAngleX:0];

[self runAction: [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:orbit]];
```

But what i need is having it flip over its y axis, sort of like a dummy getting up in a shooting range.

Can you give me any pointers? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up faking it by scaling the sprite vertically instead. Not as pretty but it did the job.

Answer (score 2):

```
CCOrbitCamera * orbit = [CCOrbitCamera actionWithDuration:2 radius:1 deltaRadius:0 angleZ:0 deltaAngleZ:360 angleX:90 deltaAngleX:0]
```

changing angleX to 90 will change the rotation axis